# Javascript: I found this small bit of code, does it copy text to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I found this in the js source here: http://www.clae.com/jscripts/common.js

I don't know what this does, does it copy text to the clipboard? i thought it was impossible for JS to copy text to the clipboard?

```
// Copies passed text to the clipboard
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.findText(text);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        document.execCommand("Unselect");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that cross-browser. Check this out: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html

Answer (score 0):

This works on IE and FireFox... I tested those today:

MENU ITEM a-tag:  `onclick="javascript:copyText()"`

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function copyText() {
    if(document.all){
    //  IE - copy the selected text
        var selection = document.selection;
        var CopiedTxt = selection.createRange();
        CopiedTxt.select();
        CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");
        copiedtext=window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
        // alert("IE=" + copiedtext);
    } else{
    //  FF - copy the selected text
        var start=thisElementObject.selectionStart;
        var end=thisElementObject.selectionEnd;
        thisSelectedText=thisElementObject.value.substring(start, end);
        // alert("FF=" + thisSelectedText); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I see how the Firefox version grabs the selected text, assuming you've set thisElementObject correctly. But how does it copy it to the clipboard?